# Google Doc to PDF export Bug depending on User

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

BUG: Exporting as PDF while not on superuser account occurs. The first 1-2 images load into the PDF file and the rest do not.

I utilize Google apps scripts and to eliminate that as the issue I did the process manually. I went to the google doc. File-> Export As-> PDF.

It produced the same BUG. When following those same steps logged in as superuser it downloaded the full file and all images.

I have tried:

- Multiple Browsers
- Removing all app permissions on the account
- Different PDF programs
- Smaller file sizes (Max 8mb - Min 2mb)

All which kept producing the same issue.

The weird thing is if I click 'File-> Export As-> (Anything EXCEPT Pdf)'. All of the images load.

Comment: Have you checked [this google help forum discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/JGgYGBFehTU)?

Comment: I have thank you. No helpful answers there. I will submit a bug report but hope to find someone with a work around.